# why terminal auto duplicate letter when I type -

Tags: terminal, terminal.app

I just got this weird behavior, does anyone know how to stop it?

When I type 'dir' then '-' terminal gives me this 'ddir-'

And here is the video of that https://youtu.be/lGsFB68zVIo

Comment: What is your `PS1` and `PROMPT_COMMAND`? I suspect one of them contains a control character not properly enclosed between `"\["` and `"\]"` (PS1) or `0x01` and `0x02` bytes (PROMPT_COMMAND).

Comment: How can I check my my PS1 or PROMPT_COMMAND?

Comment: To see all the potential invisible characters in them, I recommend `set | grep ^PS1` and similarly for the other.

Comment: it shows this PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '

Comment: other one show this PROMPT_COMMAND=update_terminal_cwd
        if [ "$PROMPT_COMMAND" = "shell_session_history_check" ]; then
            unset PROMPT_COMMAND;
            if [[ $PROMPT_COMMAND =~ (.*)(; *shell_session_history_check *| *shell_session_history_check *; *)(.*) ]]; then
                PROMPT_COMMAND="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because I set input source to other language rather english

[image]